# How to give different - 2 color to text written in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to change color of text written in `JTextArea`.  For e.g. I am pasting Java code in `JTextArea`.

I want to give the different-2 color to Java keywords, variables and classes written in code.

Is it possible?

Comment: `JTextArea` is a plain text component.  Use a component designed for formatted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Rob Camick's [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/).  It seems perfect for this use case.

[image: Message Console]

---

Actually '2 color' might not be enough for this.
See [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more details on the formatted text components that might replace `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible
if you want to set different colors in the same area, i think JTextPane could help you
i'm not sure how to use that, but i found this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html